# Postgres settings reported differently in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We are running PostgreSQL 9.2 on CentOS 6 and I am seeing the settings are reported differently when I run the `show effective_cache_size;` command vs `select * from pg_settings where name = 'effective_cache_size';` query. As far as I can understand these commands should be identical. For example

```
show effective_cache_size;

effective_cache_size
----------------------
 2816MB
(1 row)
```

vs

```
select name,setting from pg_settings where name = 'effective_cache_size';

name    | effective_cache_size

setting | 360448
```

I am trying to figure out the value used by PostgreSQL. I get the same results if I run this as a superuser. Which one do I trust?

Comment: In your question you talk about `shared buffers`, yet your example shows `effective_cache_size`.

Comment: Isn't "effective_cache_size" a parameter that can be set on cluster and on session level?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited the question to match the example output, thanks.

Comment: @colin-t-hart no setting has been done to this param besides the config file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the same difference on my test database:

```
show shared_buffers;
 shared_buffers 
────────────────
 768MB


select name, setting from pg_settings where name = 'shared_buffers';
      name      │ setting 
────────────────┼─────────
 shared_buffers │ 98304
```

Then watching the numbers for a short while, I set up the following query:

```
SELECT 98304 * 8192 / (1024 * 1024);
 ?column? 
──────────
      768
```

So, to me it looks like that `pg_settings` reports these sizes in 8 kb pages (8192 refers to this fact).

Note that there is a third way to check settings, namely the `current_setting()` function:

```
SELECT current_setting('shared_buffer');
 current_setting
-----------------
 768MB
```

Comment: thanks @dezso for the explanation, same calculation applies for my sample as well